# Can get json from .txt file but not from php generated json using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, getjson

Hi I am trying to run an ajax query using jquery. If I use a locally stored .txt file I get no problems. The problem comes whenever I try to query a php generated json. Here it is the code:

```
$('#find').click(function(){
$.getJSON('http://localhost/public/ProductCatalog/searchindex/txt.php', function(data) {
var items = []; 
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
        pushStr = '<div class="prod-container">';
        pushStr += '   <div class="prod-image-container"><img class="prod-img" src="' + val['foto'] + '"/></div>';
        pushStr += '    <div class="prod-desc-container">' + val['title'] + '</div>';
        pushStr += '    <input class="id" type="hidden" value="' + val['id'] + '"/>';
        pushStr += '    <input class="title" type="hidden" value="' + val['title'] + '"/>';
        pushStr += '</div>';
        items.push(pushStr);
    });

    items.push('<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
    $('#prod-body').html(items.join(''));
    $('img.prod-img').each(function (index, element){
        fitImage(element, 75, 110);
    });
    makeDraggable();
});
});
```

So if I create a file.txt copy/pasting the same info I generate from http://localhost/public/ProductCatalog/searchindex/txt.php and use it as a parameter, then I get the content. Howerver nothing gets executed when I run the code as is.

file.txt example:

```
{
    "item1": {
        "foto": "item1.jpg",
        "title": "Teclado roland fantom-g8  las teclas con contrapeso",
        "id": "1",
        "price": "56090.25"
    },
    "item2": {
        "foto": "item2.jpg",
        "title": "Teclado roland v-piano  lo cambia todo",
        "id": "1",
        "price": "85501.79"
    },
    "item3": {
        "foto": "item3.jpg",
        "title": "Teclado roland ax-synth  teclado 49 teclas (dinÃƒ",
        "id": "1",
        "price": "13034.05"
    },
    "item4": {
        "foto": "item4.jpg",
        "title": "Teclado roland fantom g-6 fuente de sonido avanzada",
        "id": "1",
        "price": "39989.14"
    },
    "item5": {
        "foto": "item5.jpg",
        "title": "Teclado gw-8l roland gw-8l -bstock",
        "id": "1",
        "price": "11627.32"
    },
    "item6": {
        "foto": "item6.jpg",
        "title": "Teclado disney",
        "id": "1",
        "price": "605.00"
    }
}
```

here is the php code:

```
    // action body usinf zend framework
    $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender();
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open('/data/prod-catalog');
    $results = $index->find('teclado roland');
    $first = $this->_request->getParam('first');

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $i=1;

    echo '{';
    foreach ($results as $result){
        echo '"item'.$i.'": {'."\n";
        echo '    "foto": "'.$result->foto.'",'."\n";
        echo '    "title": "'.ucfirst(strtolower($result->titulo)).'",'."\n";
        echo '    "id": "'.'1'.'",'."\n";
        echo '   "price": "'.ucfirst(strtolower($result->precio)).'"'."\n";
        echo ($i<count($results) && $i<6)? '},'."\n": '}'."\n".'}'; 
        $i++;
        if($i==7){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your packet sniffer say you get instead?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand you fully, however the browser console actually downloads the file, it just does not execute anything else after that.

Comment: would you be able to post content of txt.php? Just to be sure

Comment: there it is the php code

Comment: Change val['whatever'] to val.whatever

Comment: Can you post the output of txt.php? Try using the cURL tool to output the result.

Comment: Don't output JSON by concatenating strings together! Use a real [json encoder](http://uk.php.net/json_encode).

Comment: I have encoded it as you suggested, but still no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it was a security issue. I was running the html with the js functionality in local and the server would not allow that. Once I ran it in the server it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the ' or " from your strings when you are building the JSON with addslashes().